# Открыть доступ к сайту, находящемуся на виртуальной машине

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2012

У меня поднят ownColud на Ubuntu Server. Сам Ubuntu Server стоит на виртуалке внутри Windows Server 2012 R2. На IIS в Windows уже работает сайт на 80 порту, и доступен по доменному имени mysite.ru внешнему миру. Там так же есть почтовый сервис, тоже доступен по mail.mysite.ru. Но все эти сайты работают в Windows. Если бы например и ownCloud работал в Windows проблемы бы не было, я бы просто разместил его в каталоге, и дал бы ему доменное имя cloud.mysite.ru. Но как можно сделать подобную вещь, если ownCloud у меня находиться в Ubuntu? У меня одна сеть, один роутер и один внешний IP адрес.

Comment: вам нужен [обратный прокси-сервер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8). возможно, роутер сможет выполнить его функции. или *http*-сервер в *ms/windows*.

Answer (score 2):

вам нужен [обратный прокси-сервер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8).

возможно, роутер сможет выполнить его функции. или *http-сервер*, работающий в *ms/windows*.